# Third party payment gateway for membership plans

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I want to use third party payment gateways for allowing users to subscribe to various membership plans.

Once user subscribes to any of these membership plans he will get additional services in the app as well as on website. so the content consumption is inside as well as outside of the app.

In current version which is on the app store we are using IAP for this but want to know if any third party payment gateway can be used for this kind of product.

Answer (score 0):

I have only experience with Braintree and Stripe. Both offer subscriptions/recurring billing that seems to be what you are looking for.

https://www.braintreepayments.com/products-and-features/repeat-billing
https://stripe.com/subscriptions